# Get the selected option of select2 using id of that option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Currently I am doing it without the select2 plugin and it works but I want to use select2 plugin

What I am trying to do here is get the selected option using the Select2 plugin and then do an ajax call

so if an option is selected the id will be passed and the ajax call will be done

```
$('.select2').change(function(e){         
    var arraypos = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wallfly-mvc/public/dashboard/selectedProperty',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                selected: arraypos
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#showoption').attr('id');
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Exeption:' + exception);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar The problem is that I want to use select2 plugin (https://select2.github.io/) instead of a standard select  box, which I am doing currently in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You will retrieve the selected option of a select2 input using jquery just the same you would do for a normal select input

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/2162/

```
<select id="someInputId" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>


$("#someInputId").select2();

$('#someInputId').change(function(e){         
    console.log($(this).children(":selected").attr("value"));
});
```